# How to set parameter on Crystal Reports in java desktop application

Tags: java, swing, report, crystal-reports-xi

I have a function to print a report using crystal reports. The problem is, this code prints all the data from the database. How do I set a parameter or a filter programmatically so I can just select which record to present on my report. I know that theres a prompt to ask a value for the parameter on crystal reports itself but I dont want to use that.

```
private void openReport() {

    try {
        ReportClientDocument rpt =  new ReportClientDocument();
        rpt.open(reportPath+fileName, 0);

        rpt.getDatabaseController().logon(mdlLogin.dbUsername, mdlLogin.dbPassword);
        Tables tables = rpt.getDatabaseController().getDatabase().getTables();

        for(int i=0; i< tables.size(); i++){
            ITable table = tables.getTable(i);
            // dbane.owner.tablename
            String original_qualifiedName = table.getQualifiedName();
            String new_qualifierName = original_qualifiedName;

            switch (database) {
            case "ORACLE":
                // SCHEMA.TABLENAME
                String tableName = StringUtils.substringAfterLast(original_qualifiedName, ".").toUpperCase(); 
                new_qualifierName = userOrSchemaName.toUpperCase()+"."+tableName;

                break;
            case "INFORMIX":
                // DATABASE.OWNER.TABLENAME
                new_qualifierName = dbname + ":" + userOrSchemaName + "." + StringUtils.substringAfterLast(original_qualifiedName, ".");                    

                break;
            case "MySQL":
                // DATABASE.OWNER.TABLENAME
                new_qualifierName = dbname + "." + userOrSchemaName + "." + StringUtils.substringAfterLast(original_qualifiedName, ".");                    
                new_qualifierName = dbname + "." + StringUtils.substringAfterLast(original_qualifiedName, ".");                    
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

            String jdbcConnectionString = null;
            String preQEServerName = null;
            String driver = null;

            switch (database) {
            case "INFORMIX":
                // !com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver!jdbc:informix-sqli://localhost:40421/export:INFORMIXSERVER=cargool1!user={userid}!password={password}
                jdbcConnectionString = "!com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver!jdbc:informix-sqli://"+ip+":"+port+"/"+dbname+":INFORMIXSERVER="+dbservername+"!user={userid}!password={password}";
                // jdbc:informix-sqli://localhost:40421/export:INFORMIXSERVER=cargool1
                preQEServerName      = "jdbc:informix-sqli://"+ip+":"+port+"/"+dbname+":INFORMIXSERVER="+dbservername;
                // com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver
                driver = "com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver";
                break;
            case "MySQL":
                // !com.mysql.jdbc.Driver!jdbc:mysql://172.20.9.170:3306/hego
                jdbcConnectionString = "!com.mysql.jdbc.Driver!jdbc:mysql://"+ip+":"+port+"/"+dbname;
                // jdbc:mysql://172.20.9.170:3306/customer
                preQEServerName      = "jdbc:mysql://"+ip+":"+port+"/"+dbname;
                // com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
                driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
                break;
            case "ORACLE":
                // !oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver!jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:50000/tmsddb2
                jdbcConnectionString = "!oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver!jdbc:oracle:thin:@//"+ip+":"+port+"/"+dbname;
                // jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:50000/tmsddb2
                preQEServerName      = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//"+ip+":"+port+"/"+dbname;
                // "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
                driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

            table.setQualifiedName(new_qualifierName);

            ConnectionInfo connInfo = new ConnectionInfo();                

            PropertyBag innerProp = new PropertyBag();
            innerProp.put("JDBC Connection String", jdbcConnectionString);
            innerProp.put("PreQEServerName",   preQEServerName);
            innerProp.put("Server Type", "JDBC (JNDI)");
            innerProp.put("Database DLL", "crdb_jdbc.dll");
            innerProp.put("Database", dbname);
            innerProp.put("Database Class Name", driver);
            innerProp.put("Use JDBC", "true");
            innerProp.put("Database Name", dbname);
            innerProp.put("Server Name", preQEServerName);
            innerProp.put("Connection URL", preQEServerName);

            connInfo.setAttributes(innerProp);
            connInfo.setUserName(mdlLogin.dbUsername);
            connInfo.setPassword(mdlLogin.dbPassword);

            table.setConnectionInfo(connInfo);
            rpt.getDatabaseController().setTableLocation(table, tables.getTable(i));
        }
        /*
         * SubReport
         * 
         */

        int numTables = rpt.getSubreportController().getSubreportNames().size();

        for(int i=0; i<numTables; i++){////////////

            String str = rpt.getSubreportController().getSubreportNames().getString(i);

            Tables subTables = rpt.getSubreportController().getSubreport(str).getDatabaseController().getDatabase().getTables();

            for(int j=0; j< subTables.size(); j++){
                ITable table = subTables.getTable(j);
                // dbane.owner.tablename
                String original_qualifiedName = table.getQualifiedName();
                String new_qualifierName = original_qualifiedName;

                switch (database) {
                case "ORACLE":
                    // SCHEMA.TABLENAME
                    String tableName = StringUtils.substringAfterLast(original_qualifiedName, ".").toUpperCase(); 
                    new_qualifierName = userOrSchemaName.toUpperCase()+"."+tableName;

                    break;
                case "INFORMIX":
                    // DATABASE.OWNER.TABLENAME
                    new_qualifierName = dbname + ":" + userOrSchemaName + "." + StringUtils.substringAfterLast(original_qualifiedName, ".");                    

                    break;
                case "MySQL":
                    // DATABASE.OWNER.TABLENAME
//                    new_qualifierName = dbname + "." + userOrSchemaName + "." + StringUtils.substringAfterLast(original_qualifiedName, ".");                    
                    new_qualifierName = dbname + "." + StringUtils.substringAfterLast(original_qualifiedName, ".");                    
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }

                String jdbcConnectionString = null;
                String preQEServerName = null;
                String driver = null;

                switch (database) {
                case "INFORMIX":
                    // !com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver!jdbc:informix-sqli://localhost:40421/export:INFORMIXSERVER=cargool1!user={userid}!password={password}
                    jdbcConnectionString = "!com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver!jdbc:informix-sqli://"+ip+":"+port+"/"+dbname+":INFORMIXSERVER="+dbservername+"!user={userid}!password={password}";
                    // jdbc:informix-sqli://localhost:40421/export:INFORMIXSERVER=cargool1
                    preQEServerName      = "jdbc:informix-sqli://"+ip+":"+port+"/"+dbname+":INFORMIXSERVER="+dbservername;
                    // com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver
                    driver = "com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver";
                    break;
                case "MySQL":
                    // !com.mysql.jdbc.Driver!jdbc:mysql://172.20.9.170:3306/hego
                    jdbcConnectionString = "!com.mysql.jdbc.Driver!jdbc:mysql://"+ip+":"+port+"/"+dbname;
                    // jdbc:mysql://172.20.9.170:3306/customer
                    preQEServerName      = "jdbc:mysql://"+ip+":"+port+"/"+dbname;
                    // com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
                    driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
                    break;
                case "ORACLE":
                    // !oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver!jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:50000/tmsddb2
                    jdbcConnectionString = "!oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver!jdbc:oracle:thin:@//"+ip+":"+port+"/"+dbname;
                    // jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:50000/tmsddb2
                    preQEServerName      = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//"+ip+":"+port+"/"+dbname;
                    // "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
                    driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }

                table.setQualifiedName(new_qualifierName);

                ConnectionInfo connInfo = new ConnectionInfo();                

                PropertyBag innerProp = new PropertyBag();
                innerProp.put("JDBC Connection String", jdbcConnectionString);
                innerProp.put("PreQEServerName",   preQEServerName);
                innerProp.put("Server Type", "JDBC (JNDI)");
                innerProp.put("Database DLL", "crdb_jdbc.dll");
                innerProp.put("Database", dbname);
                innerProp.put("Database Class Name", driver);
                innerProp.put("Use JDBC", "true");
                innerProp.put("Database Name", dbname);
                innerProp.put("Server Name", preQEServerName);
                innerProp.put("Connection URL", preQEServerName);

                connInfo.setAttributes(innerProp);
                connInfo.setUserName(mdlLogin.dbUsername);
                connInfo.setPassword(mdlLogin.dbPassword);

                table.setConnectionInfo(connInfo);
                rpt.getSubreportController().getSubreport(str).getDatabaseController().setTableLocation(table, subTables.getTable(j));
            }
        }//////////////////////////

//            rpt.getPrintOutputController().export(ReportExportFormat.RTF)

        ReportViewerBean viewer = new ReportViewerBean();
        viewer.init(new String[0], null, null, null);
        viewer.setHasGroupTree(false);
        viewer.setReportSource(rpt.getReportSource());
        viewer.setHasExportButton(false);
        viewer.setShowLogo(false);
        viewer.start();
        frmReportPanel panel = new frmReportPanel(rpt,fileName.replace(".rpt", ""));

        Component[] components = viewer.getContentPane().getComponents();

        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        panel.add(components[0], BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(components[1], BorderLayout.CENTER);

        clsMain.openTab(fileName.replace(".rpt", ""), panel);


    } catch (HeadlessException | ReportSDKExceptionBase | PropertyVetoException exception) {
        Logger.getLogger(frmReportList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, exception);
        utilErrorHandler.printError(exception.toString(), exception.getMessage(), M_STRPANELNAME, "PrintReport");
    }
}
```

Comment: *"but I dont want to use that."*  Why not?

Comment: I dont want my user to fill up the requested parameter since the value for the parameter is on my program already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to answer it by these codes

```
ParameterFieldController paramController=rpt.getDataDefController().getParameterFieldController();
paramController.setCurrentValue("",parameterField,Integer.parseInt(parameterValue));
```